# Exporting uitable data to excel using matlab for macintosh

Tags: excel, matlab, user-interface, matlab-uitable

I am stuck trying to export matlab uitable data to excel. I tried many things, and It has been impossible to solve this problem. After many days, I tried the code below using windows and it does work perfect, however, using the same for Macintosh is not longer working. The output is as follows:

"Error using dlmwrite (line 118) The input cell array cannot be converted to a matrix"

Searching for more information, I found an answer here ,([Using "xlswrite" MATLABs for cell arrays containing strings of different size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784493/using-xlswrite-matlabs-for-cell-arrays-containing-strings-of-different-size)) which doesn't work perfect. Finally I found this method which applies only for matlab using windows (http://www.mathworks.es/matlabcentral/answers/20819-export-uitable-s-data-to-a-spreadsheet-excel).

I hope you can help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance

Hector

```
function Save_File

hf = figure;

hExportButton = uicontrol('Parent',hf,'Units',...
'normalized','Position',[0 0.81 0.22 0.18],'Style','Pushbutton',....
'String',' Export Data!','FontSize',20,'Callback',@ExportButton_Callback);

dat = rand(5,5); 

t=uitable('Data',dat,'ColumnName',{'First','Second','Third','Fourth','Fifth'},...
'Position',[7 10 500 300]);

Data=get(t,'Data');
ColumnName=get(t,'ColumnName');
set(t,'ColumnWidth',{93.5})


function ExportButton_Callback(~,~)

NewData= num2cell(Data,ones(size(Data,1),1),ones(size(Data,2),1));
CombData=[ColumnName';NewData];
FileName = uiputfile('*.xls','Save as');
xlswrite(FileName,CombData);  
end

end
```

Comment: The issue is likely that you have an array that contains both strings and numbers, these can not be placed together into a single matrix, I would recommend simply writing your file line by line as a csv. A csv file can be opened by Excel

Comment: This doesn't even work in R2013b. Don't bother with `xlswrite`. Have you checked out the MathWorks FileExchange? There seem to be [several options available](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/index?utf8=✓&term=xlswrite) that don't even require Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to convert the cell array into a number array with a `cell2mat` command and then use `csvwrite` or `dlmwrite`.

If the combo of numbers and strings is the issue, as stated in my comment above, you can use some simple looping to do this all for you. I posted some sample code below.

```
% Creating some temporary data for proof of concept
mat = randi([1,5],10,2);
header = {'Col1','Col2'};
cellVals = [header;num2cell(mat)];

% the real code that does the writing
fh = fopen('temp.csv','w'); % open a file with write privileges, will overwrite old versions
for ii = 1:size(cellVals,1)
    first = 1;
    for  jj = 1:size(cellVals,2)
        if first
            fwrite(fh,num2str(cellVals{ii,jj},'%f'));
            first = 0;
        else
            fwrite(fh,[',',num2str(cellVals{ii,jj},'%f')]);
        end
    end
    fwrite(fh,sprintf('\r\n')); % print line break
end
fclose(fh); % close file out when done writing
```

Comment: Don't use `num2str` with no second argument for floating-point inputs. `sprintf('%.17g',cellVals{ii,jj}))` would be much better anyways.

Comment: Dear @MZimmerman6,

Thank you for your help and suggestions. Your sample code works great.

Thank you very much for your kind help!!!!

Comment: @horchler good catch. Note all format flags are seen [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html#btf97wk)

Comment: Dear @MZimmerman6,

I adapted your sample to my code and it works great. However, I have a new problem, the first cell contains a string instead of number and when I run the code, the first cell shows the NaN message. What can I do in that case?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand where you are having trouble. Can you edit your question to show an example of what you mean

Comment: Dear @MZimmerman6, the data of the uitable I would like to export to CSV is from 5 edit boxes. One of them is an "ID" (Data entered by the user which should be a character, nor a digit) and the last 4 of them are numbers (results from different calculation performed by the gui). Using your sample, I can export the numbers, but not the ID, which result should be shown in the first cell of the uitable exported. Thank you in advance!.

Héctor

Comment: As long as you put all of your data into a cell array, regardless of it being text or numbers, the looping portion of my code will work because it converts everything to a string anyway before writing to the file. It is on you to make sure you have a cell array. My code is meant to be a starting point not the complete solution because I do not have your data, I do not have your GUI, nor do I want it.